What does the bare default "John *hash.file*" command do in John the Ripper?
Looking at Openwall documentation, it does not explicitly say what the john command with no parameters passed does. The community wiki they have links to a bunch of external sites. And the first several of them I have checked never say what using no parameters will do. They say stuff like to do a dictionary attack, pass the parameter --wordlist='rockyou.txt'. And how to use a mask attack.
So I ask Super User where Google has failed me, what does simply using John hash.file do? Does it default to a wordlist? It seems like it based on the progress I see. I don't know what p/s, c/s, and C/S are, but they're all the same, so it makes me think that I'm not using any masks in the default set up, which means if the wordlist it's deriving from has no capitals, then no capitals are being attempted on the hash I am trying to match.
Let this run for a week and I'm thinking it's not even covering capitals, so I may as well start over. And figure out getting it to use my GPU.
0g 1:05:48:29 2.23% 2/3 (ETA: 2024-09-15 04:55) 0g/s 970.7p/s 970.7c/s 970.7C/s birstlove0..bniffi
0g 1:09:03:17 2.52% 2/3 (ETA: 2024-09-14 06:43) 0g/s 971.6p/s 971.6c/s 971.6C/s 1993041266..shamna66
0g 1:17:50:02 3.12% 2/3 (ETA: 2024-09-15 11:59) 0g/s 967.1p/s 967.1c/s 967.1C/s 123471116..trumpy116
0g 1:20:12:37 3.28% 2/3 (ETA: 2024-09-15 18:43) 0g/s 966.9p/s 966.9c/s 966.9C/s beagle1785..brittb85
0g 2:07:01:18 4.04% 2/3 (ETA: 2024-09-16 06:37) 0g/s 965.7p/s 965.7c/s 965.7C/s 7300467..7daemon1
0g 3:00:01:13 5.24% 2/3 (ETA: 2024-09-16 19:21) 0g/s 965.4p/s 965.4c/s 965.4C/s annibelle171..lookma71
0g 3:00:50:34 5.30% 2/3 (ETA: 2024-09-16 20:34) 0g/s 965.7p/s 965.7c/s 965.7C/s 2shibby06..2whiterose4
0g 3:18:35:14 6.55% 2/3 (ETA: 2024-09-17 05:23) 0g/s 965.1p/s 965.1c/s 965.1C/s bchaz93..b111213k
0g 4:05:08:14 7.26% 2/3 (ETA: 2024-09-17 14:39) 0g/s 964.2p/s 964.2c/s 964.2C/s gavin82x..440777x
0g 5:07:50:29 9.48% 2/3 (ETA: 2024-09-15 18:33) 0g/s 969.3p/s 969.3c/s 969.3C/s poteyee..1ttwers
0g 6:01:30:55 10.83% 2/3 (ETA: 2024-09-15 13:18) 0g/s 966.7p/s 966.7c/s 966.7C/s candy20021988..dad19911988
0g 6:18:53:04 12.05% 2/3 (ETA: 2024-09-15 21:42) 0g/s 964.9p/s 964.9c/s 964.9C/s meredith021983..dantheman691983
0g 7:00:26:01 12.55% 2/3 (ETA: 2024-09-15 12:12) 0g/s 964.7p/s 964.7c/s 964.7C/s 12345567892003..taylor282003
0g 7:05:07:39 12.89% 2/3 (ETA: 2024-09-15 13:02) 0g/s 964.5p/s 964.5c/s 964.5C/s 2324d5262728..berudaha
0g 7:19:43:12 14.06% 2/3 (ETA: 2024-09-15 04:56) 0g/s 966.3p/s 966.3c/s 966.3C/s isabeya14..electya12

